# Junit 5: Difference between @SpringBootTest and @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)

Tags: junit5

Testing with Junit5, Can I use only @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) without @SpringBootTest ?
Some resources say that @SpringBootTest already include @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class), is this correct ?
When I run the test with @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) only, I notice that the test is very light and doesn't load the entire application context, but I'm not sure if I don't use @SpringBootTest my unit test is considered complete or correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` without loading the entire application context that is included with `@SpringBootTest`. As you say it's a lighter weight approach if you just want to mock beans with `@MockBean`. `@SpringBootTest` does in fact include `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` but it may be overkill for what you are trying to achieve.